# Disable SSL Certificate validation on Android and/or Amazon Services

Tags: android, ssl, amazon-s3

I'm getting the intermittent error, "Unable to execute HTTP request: No peer certificate." When trying to putObject to my S3 bucket.

This is due to Amazon not sending the right SSL Certificate.

The fix, according to Amazon is:
http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html
**but this is not applicable to android**

I would like to disable the SSL Certificate validation on Android and or Amazon Services.
I'm aware of the "man in the middle" possibility, this will only be disabled for very short periods of time.

Any information would be helpful.

Comment: Since the blog post that you linked to seems to have the solution, what specifically is your problem?

Comment: its not meant for android

Comment: What makes you think that "this is not applicable to Android"?